# Deriving generic type from generic ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have two types that extend the generic ArrayList type.

```
public class BuyersGuideResponse extends ArrayList<BuyersGuideItem>
{

    private void checkStatusAttributes(){ ... }
    private void addItems(){ ... }
}

public class CatalogEngineTypeResponse extends ArrayList<CatalogEngineType>
{

    private void checkStatusAttributes(){ ... }
    private void addItems(){ ... }
}
```

The checkStatusAttributes method is identical in both types so I'd like to create a abstract generic intermediate type. I currently have

```
public class ArrayListResponse extends ArrayList<Object>
{

// no implementation

}

public class BuyersGuideResponse<BuyersGuideItem> extends ArrayListResponse
{

    // implementation unchanged
    ...
    private void addItems()
    {
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(CatalogConst.BUYERS_GUIDE_ITEM_NODE_NAME);
        for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
        {
            add(new BuyersGuideItem(nodes.item(i)));
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

When compiling the following error is generated :

```
BuyersGuideResponse.java:51: error: unexpected type

        add(new BuyersGuideItem(nodes.item(i)));
                ^

    required: class

    found: type parameter BuyersGuideItem

    where BuyersGuideItem is a type-variable

        BuyersGuideItem extends Object declared in BuyersGuideItem.java
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When used in a top level class declaration, the part between `<>` is a type parameter, not a type argument.

Comment: this could help you in extending a generic class : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417930/extending-generic-abstract-class-correct-use-of-super

Comment: in summary - share the generic type parameter between the base and derived class, like this : public class Tool<AT> extends AbstractTool<AT>

Answer (score 4):

This declaration

```
public class BuyersGuideResponse<BuyersGuideItem> extends ArrayListResponse
```

is equivalent to

```
public class BuyersGuideResponse<T> extends ArrayListResponse
```

so you can see why that wouldn't work. It would try to do

```
 add(new T(nodes.item(i)));
```

The type parameter is shadowing the name of the type.

I would do the following

```
public class ArrayListResponse<T> extends ArrayList<T>
```

for your parent class.

```
public class BuyersGuideResponse extends ArrayListResponse<BuyersGuideItem>
```

for your child implementation. Here `BuyersGuideItem` is a type argument and won't hide the type name.

Comment: @A.G. Please mark the question as resolved by choosing the answer above. Thanks!