# Trouble with extending abstract generic class

Tags: java, generics

I need to create a `JTextField` that forces only certain kinds of input (I have a goal for certain functionality that precludes using `JFormattedTextField`). To accomplish this, I would like to create an `abstract JTextField` class with generics:

```
abstract class VTextField_Core<E> extends JTextField {
    public abstract E getAmount();
    public abstract <E> void setAmount(E amount);
}
```

And implement it in a way like this:

```
class VTextField_Integer<Integer> extends VTextField_Core {

    @Override
    public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
        // format Integer to text
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getAmount() {
        // parse text and return Integer
    }
}

class VTextField_Double<Double> extends VTextField_Core {

    @Override
    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        // format Double to text
    }

    @Override
    public Double getAmount() {
        // parse text and return Double
    }
}
```

But this gives a compiler error:

```
name clash: setAmount(Integer) in Test2.VTextField_Integer and <E>setAmount(E) in Test2.VTextField_Core have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
  where Integer,E are type-variables:
    Integer extends Object declared in class Test2.VTextField_Integer
    E extends Object declared in method <E>setAmount(E)
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working. How do you extend an abstract generic superclass and implement it?

Based on this question: [Extending Generic Abstract Class & Correct Use of Super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417930/extending-generic-abstract-class-correct-use-of-super)

I tried:

```
class VTextField_Integer<Integer> extends VTextField_Core<Integer> {
class VTextField_Integer<Integer> extends VTextField_Core<E> {
```

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`class VTextField_Integer<Integer>` declares a type parameter named `Integer`, which is not what you need.

Change your classes to:

```
class VTextField_Integer extends VTextField_Core<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
        // format Integer to text
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getAmount() {
        // parse text and return Integer
    }
}

class VTextField_Double extends VTextField_Core<Double> {

    @Override
    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        // format Double to text
    }

    @Override
    public Double getAmount() {
        // parse text and return Double
    }
}
```

And you don't need the type parameter `<E>` in the `setAmount` method of the abstract class.

```
abstract class VTextField_Core<E> extends JTextField {
    public abstract E getAmount();
    public abstract void setAmount(E amount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your method as:

```
public abstract void setAmount(E amount);
```

i.e. don't declare a new type variable.

This method signature:

```
public abstract <E> void setAmount(E amount);
```

says that the method has to accept *any* `Object`. You can't change this in subclasses to only accept *some* objects.

Comment: To be clear here: although they have the same name, the type parameter of generic method `setAmount()` is completely separate and distinct from the type parameter of generic class `VTextField_Core` (good catch!).  In this case, the problem could also be solved by making the parent-class method an *ordinary* one, using the class's type parameter for its argument type.